# Knockstrap popover not working with require.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, requirejs

I'm trying to introduce a few bootstrap 3 elements, particularly alert and popover into a project that uses knockout, using knockstrap for handling bindings.

The alert and button elements work as expected (and is proof that Knockstrap is loaded and working to some degree),

```
<div class="alert" data-bind="alert:{ type: alertType, message: alertMessage }"></div>

<button id="btnToggle" class="btn btn-info inline" data-bind="toggle: isToggled">Toggle button</button>
```

but the popover element doesn't work at all, I have also experimented with tooltip with similar lack of success.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="popover: {
                options: { title: 'Popover with template', placement: 'bottom' },
                template: popoverTemplate,
                data: { text: 'First template' }
            }">
            Click
        </button>
```

In both cases the error received in chrome is: ".xxxxx is not a function"

```
TypeError: Unable to process binding "popover: function (){return {
                    options:{ title:'Popover with template',placement:'bottom'},template:popoverTemplate,data:{ text:'First template'}} }"
Message: h.popover is not a function
```

Googling around lead me to suspect that I had duplicate versions of jquery (as i use jquery elsewhere in my project) but when I distill my project down to just the essential elements, I still receive the same error. [See my test page](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/17727/) with a few mods (baseUrl has to be different, main isn't required) to get require to work in jsfiddle. The behaviour or lack of it, is the same.

```
requirejs.config({
appDir: ".",
baseUrl: '../Scripts/js/lib',
paths: {
    /* Load jquery from cdnjs. On fail, load local file. */
    'jquery': ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min', '../../jquery-min'],
    /* Load knockout from cdnjs. On fail, load local file. */
    'knockout': ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min', 'knockout/knockout-min'],
    /* Load knockstrap from cdnjs. On fail, load local file. */
    'knockstrap': ['//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/knockstrap@1.4.0/build/knockstrap', 'knockstrap/knockstrap-min'],
    'main': 'main'
}
```

});

```
require(['knockout', 'knockstrap'], function (ko, knockstrap) {

    // adding knockstrap to dependancies works for alerts, not for popovers? (TypeError ... $element.popover is not a function, line 843)

    function PopoverExampleViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        // Tooltip bindings
        self.tooltipTitle = ko.observable('Observable title');
        self.tooltipPlacement = ko.observable('left');

        // Alert bindings
        self.alertMessage = ko.observable('Alert Test Message');
        self.alertType = ko.observable('info');

        // Popover bindings
        self.popoverTemplate = ko.observable('firstPopoverTemplate');
        self.switchTemplates = function () {
            self.popoverTemplate() === 'firstPopoverTemplate' ? self.popoverTemplate('secondPopoverTemplate') : self.popoverTemplate('firstPopoverTemplate');
        };

        // Toggle Buttton bindings
        self.isToggled = ko.observable(false);
    }
    var model = new PopoverExampleViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(model);
});
```

Stripping it down even further, to just a plain html file with just the bare minimum js files, ie duplicating the example code from the Knockstrap site and excluding require.js then both alert and popover work.

Can someone please help me understand why alerts are working and popovers are not. Or what would be the best solution to providing popovers in knockout? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: can you create a fiddle replicating this issue?

Comment: my test page is a jsfiddle page https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/17727/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on bootstrap documentation, popover component needs javascript to run correctly. Thus, you'll have to load bootstrap.min.js in the paths and use a shim so that it can load knockstrap correctly when all jquery, knockout, and bootstrap have been loaded.

Here is the modified jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gbhkahmk/22/

```
paths: { 
    ...,
    'bootstrap': ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min', '/libs/bootstrap-min']
},
shim: {
    bootstrap: {
    deps: ['jquery']
  },
  knockstrap: {
    deps: ['knockout', 'jquery', 'bootstrap']
  }
}
```